# How to Round and Format Mail Merge Number

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, mailmerge, fieldcodes

I have an amount that fluctuates from 1 million to over a billion and want to show the result as $1.5 million or $1.5 billion using the field codes in Word 2013 for a mail merge. (ie. 1,500,000 should display $1.5 million and 1,500,000,000 should display as $1.5 billion.)

I have this so far:

```
{=int({MERGEFIELD AreaSales})/100000000 \# $,0.0}
```

Which gives me close to what I'm looking for $1.5 but without accounting for an amount in the millions or billions and the proper label. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want to deal with (a) round numbers, e.g. should 10000000 be displayed as "$10 million" or "$10.0 million" and (b) rounding - e.g. should 999999999.99 display as  "$1,000 million", "$1,000.0 million", "$1 billion", "$1.0 billion, "$999.9 million" or what?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're asking - you should always provide examples of what you want to have. I'm assuming what you mean is you want to see the word "million" or "billion", as appropriate. This can be done using a separate IF field:

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD AreaSales } > 999999.99 "{ IF { MERGEFIELD AreaSales } < 1000000000 "million" "billion" }" "" }
```